# php Nest while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, nested

I have this nested while loop that seems like it should work but the inner loop only runs once. The reason I have to keep running the query is because every Year will have different months associated with that year.

The output is expected to be 
2013 > April
       May
2014 > July

The actual output is
2013 > April 
2014 > July

```
while ($row_year = mysqli_fetch_array($result_year, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $nest_usage_data_year[] = $row_year;
    echo ("<li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"#\">"
    . $nest_usage_data_year[$y]['days']
    . "<i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i></a>");
    $result_month = mysqli_query($dbc,
    "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(days, '%M') "
    . "As days FROM energy_history "
    . "WHERE serial_number = '".$_SESSION['serial_number']."' "
    . "AND DATE_FORMAT(days, '%Y') = '"
    .  $nest_usage_data_year[$y]['days']."' "); //add AND month to filter

    $y++;

    // This while is only iterating once...
    while ($row_month = mysqli_fetch_array($result_month))
    {
        $nest_usage_data_month[] = $row_month;
        echo (" <ul style=\"display: none;\" class=\"dropdown-menu sub-menu-level1 bold\">");
        echo ("<li><a href=\"#\">".$nest_usage_data_month[$m]['days']."</a></li>");
        echo ("</ul>");
        echo ("</li>");
        $m++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please please *please* properly format your code before pasting it into your question.

Comment: Thanks for editing my code..I was having trouble figuring out the system here.

The output is expected to be
2013 > April
May
2014 > July
August